# jquery not working inside html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do a very basic jquery tutorial but I'm not able to get it to work.
I'm calling the jquery library from google and then I try to create a script inside html.

If I do the same in a .js file I wouldn't have any problem.
What am I missing here?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("a").click(function() {
                    alert("Hello world!");
                });
            });
        </script>
            <a href="">Link</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to split this up:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            alert("Hello world!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

...into two script elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            alert("Hello world!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

In the snippet you gave, the code within the `<script>` element won't be evaluated because the browser is only evaluating the contents from the `src` attribute and ignoring everything else.

Comment: The amount of time I've spent on something so dumb is insane. I never thought it required 2 elements. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. We've all been there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Move your scripts into the head element like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a").click(function () {
                alert("Hello world!");
            }); 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>    
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</body>
</html>
```